# How to install appcelerator titanium on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, installation

I downloaded the available [zip file](http://titanium-studio.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/titanium.linux.gtk.x86.zip) which -from its name- seems to be gtk,

and when trying to run TitaniumStudio as explained in the installation guide

> run the TitaniumStudio executable

I get this error msg

> There is no application installed for executable files.
>   Do you want to search for an application to open this file?

Comment: This might get better traction at http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I had done.

Unzip the downloaded file and copy the folder Titanium_Studio to /opt (you may have to use sudo privilege to copy). It need not be in /opt. In that case, please modify the desktop entry appropriately.

Create a desktop entry.

```
geordee@ubuntu:~/.local/share/applications$ cat TitaniumStudio.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Titanium Studio
Exec=/opt/Titanium_Studio/TitaniumStudio
Icon=/opt/Titanium_Studio/icon.xpm
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
```

Click on Ubuntu button and type Titanium. Click on the icon. You can then lock the program to Launcher too.

Comment: Did your instructions but all I get is a blank icon for Titanium Studio and nothing happens when clicking it !!

Comment: Which directory Titanium Studio is unzipped and copied to? Is there a file called TitaniumStudio there? Is there a file called icon.xpm in that directory?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked like lot of times in the internet and havent seen a solid answer or someone got this working. I had this problem for like 2 weeks and finally I managed to solve it. Meaning I have just installed Titanium 5.x on Ubuntu 15.10 successfully after like 2 weeks non-stop tedious attempts. I have seen this problem of Titanium forums and StackOverflow posts lot of times but again - NO SOLID ANSWER. ***I hope someone will be able to use this as a solution.***

I cant guarantee the correctness of this solution but these are the steps I follow.

**Install JDK**

This has to be 7 or 8 according to the official documentation.

**Install Node.js**

For linux node.js version has to be between 0.1x and 4.2x. These are the supported version according to the documentation. The latest version of node is higher than this and there is no gurantee that it will work. So I also downgraded to  4.0.0 version.

**Download and install Titanium**

You will have to sign in first and download the titanium appcelerator setup zip file. Unzip it any where. Go in to that directory and execute as any user AppeceratorStudio file. This same user should have the ownership of .npm and .appcelerator directories.
When you execute this file for the first time it just connects to appcelerator aws servers and downloads the configuration. We just cant see it . No indication what so ever. No indication in ps aux, top or netstat. So just brave your self untii this is over. This takes a looooooooooooooong time. So dont uninterrupt this. If all goes well, you have titanium.

**If uninterrupted -**>

You will have to simply to do the configration again. Luckily when you are  using Titanium CLI also you can do the configuration.

// This downloads titanium CLI and configure it

sudo npm install appcelerator -g

appc setup

After this you can run AppeceratorStudio file and start working on Titanium.

This site was helpful.

http://kalpa-gunarathna.blogspot.com/2016/01/how-to-install-titanium-appcelerator-on.html

Hope this help. :)